# jQuery updateAfterEvent like Actionscript?

Tags: jquery, actionscript-3

Is there a updateAfterEvent function like in jQuery ? I'm playing with the mouse events (mousemove, mouvedown, mouseup) while resizing some containers (divs). Even if it's smooth, i am wondering if there is way to have it smoother.. In AS3.0 updateAfterEvent makes a significant difference...

Comment: In what way? What does it do that you require to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no equivalent to ActionScript's updateAfterEvent() in jQuery.

It would not really be applicable since repaint in the browser is not tied to a fixed framerate like in the Flash Player. You could say that updateAfterEvent() is "built in" already when working with mouse events in the browser, since the browser will repaint immediately when needed automatically.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no updateAfterEvent function, but the JavaScript folks would like to say that one is already build, that is only partially true. The :) JavaScript will produce serious bugs when application is based on precise mouse behavior especially inside HTML5. Based on the speed of you processor and the complexity of the application the mouse event may not trigger at all. Actually, there are no events inside the canvas :) Canvas can have events but object events inside it are simulated trough complex calculations. In cases of processor overload the simulation system will fail or work with delay. So, the answer is - No JavaSctipt was never intended for RIA - Rich Internet Applications. As far as Jquery is concerned it is nothing more that WRITE LESS DO MORE variation of JavaScript coding style. It is not a miracle maker :) i would not advise creating any application more complex than a web site using JavaSctipt. Flash, Unity, Silverlight are much better for something like that.